# Link to a Record's Detail Page?

Tags: visualforce

I am creating a visualforce page that display an object and allows searching/sorting of the list with AngularJS. 
My code is below - How can I get the {{ c.Name }} field to hyperlink to the record's detail page?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

```
    <apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<apex:remoteObjects >
<apex:remoteObjectModel name="con_AppCatalog__c" fields="Name,Branch__c,Functional_Area__c,Description__c" jsShorthand="dbContacts"/>
</apex:remoteObjects>
<script>
                    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.sortType = 'Name'; // set the default sort type
                $scope.sortReverse = false;
                $scope.contacts=[];
                $scope.searchText='';
                $scope.fetchContacts = function() {
                    var dbCon = new SObjectModel.dbContacts();
                    console.log(dbCon);
                    dbCon.retrieve({where: {
                        or:{
                            Name: {
                                like: '%'+$scope.searchText+'%'
                            },
                            Branch__c: {
                                like: '%'+$scope.searchText+'%'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                                    limit: 500
                                   },
                                   function(err, records, event){
                                       $scope.$apply(function () {
                                           if(err) {
                                               alert(err.message);
                                           }
                                           else {
                                               $scope.contacts.splice(0,$scope.contacts.length);
                                               records.forEach(function(record) {
                                                   $scope.contacts.push({"Name" :record.get("Name"),"Functional_Area__c":record.get("Functional_Area__c"),"Description__c":record.get("Description__c"),"Branch__c":record.get("Branch__c")}); // it was % in place of $ with scope earlier
                                               });
                                           }
                                       });
                                   });
                };
            });
            </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="fetchContacts()">
<div class="well well-sm">
<h3>Contacts list with search</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<label for="searchText">Search:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="searchText" id="searchText" ng-change="fetchContacts()"/>
</div>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead><tr>
<th>
<a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
First Name
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Name' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></span>
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Name' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></span>
</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Branch__c'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
Branch
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Branch__c' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></span>
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Branch__c' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></span>
</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Functional_Area__c'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
Functional Area
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Functional_Area__c' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></span>
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Functional_Area__c' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></span>
</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Description__c'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
Description
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Description__c' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></span>
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Description__c' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></span>
</a>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="c in contacts | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
<td>{{ c.Name }} </td>
<td>{{ c.Branch__c }}</td>
<td>{{ c.Functional_Area__c }}</td>
<td>{{ c.Description__c }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>


</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question (hence me using a comment) but the URL for a record is `https://<yourSFInstanceURL>/<recordId>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searchable/Sortable Object in Visualfore](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212494/searchable-sortable-object-in-visualfore)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="ursalesforceinstanceurl/{{ c.id }}"> {{ c.Name }} </a>
```

Comment: That will hyperlink it, but for some reason it doesn't seem to pull the ID. It just takes me to an invalid page. Any ideas?

Comment: what does your generated URL look like compared to a valid Salesforce URL?

Comment: https://toolingorg--toolingsand.cs32.force.com/s/
I'm using a Community, by the way. And that's the it will direct me to, without including the ID.
But if I switch out c.id with c.Name, it adds the name to the URL just fine.
ie. https://toolingorg--toolingsand.cs32.force.com/s/Record1

Comment: make sure you put c.id in your list, hint, look at this line:                                                 $scope.contacts.push({"Name" :record.get("Name"),"Functional_Area__c":record.get("Functional_Area__c"),"Description__c":record.get("Description__c"),"Branch__c":record.get("Branch__c")});